# Is it okay to have multiple sitemaps?

Tags: google, google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap

Recently, I moved a site from http to https and the sitemaps got updated. I submitted the sitemaps to Google. There were around 9 sitemaps for the site, each of them containing pages/images the site. The site isn't very big to need more than a sitemap (around 1200 pages site). Is it ok to have 9 sitemaps covering the site or shall I recreate just 1 sitemap?

Answer (score 5):

Not long ago I was in the same boat when using WordPress plugin Yoast SEO it produced several sitemaps and I was curious to know which one to load to Google's Webmaster Tools Search Console I ran across this article on Google regarding Search Console Help:

### Simplify multiple sitemap management

If you have many sitemaps, you can use a sitemaps index file as a way to submit them at once. The XML format of a sitemap index file is very similar to the XML format of a sitemap file. The sitemap index file uses the following XML tags:

- sitemapindex - the parent tag surrounds the file.
- sitemap - the parent tag for each sitemap listed in the file (a child of sitemapindex)
- loc - the location of the sitemap (a child of sitemap)
- lastmod - the last modified date of the sitemap (optional)

Once you’ve made and saved your index file, you can submit your index file to Google as long as you upload and save all your sitemaps to the same location on your host server. You can submit up to 500 sitemap index files for each site in your account.

The article location: [Simplify multiple sitemap management](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en)